# Django problem with extends template tag

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to put variable from context processor into tag template 'extends':

```
{% extends {{ base_template|default:"mainpage.html" }} %}
```

but I got an exception:

```
Exception Value: 'extends' takes one argument
```

my context_processors.py:

```
from django.conf import settings

def search(request):

"""Adds settings for test"""
return {
        'base_template' : settings.BASE_TEMPLATE,
}
```

and settings.py:

```
...
BASE_TEMPLATE = "test/base.html"
...
```

Can you help me with that? Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Try to remove `{{}}` --> `{% extends base_template|default:"mainpage.html" %}`

Answer (score 0):

```html
{% extands %}
{% extands 'anotherpage.html'%}
like
{% extands %}
{% extands 'base.html'%}
```